Change in how Salesforce Bulk 2.0 query works over the weekend
We have been doing a bulk v2 query for a long time now and suddenly saturday morning (May 25, 2024) it began behaving differently. Prior to saturday each query would create 2 total batches, one with 0 records and one with all the queries records. Saturday morning this changed and it started batching the query into exactly 6 batches, one with 0 records and 5 with approximately the same number of records. It now is doing exactly 6 batches no matter how many records are in the query.  We haven't changed our query and the documentation for bulk api queries only says the following: for Bulk API Limits "Without PK chunking enabled, only one batch is created. If you create a batch with PK chunking enabled, batches are broken up based on the number of records in the chunk. This can range from 100,000 to 250,000 records." and for Bulk API 2.0 it only says "The API automatically handles "batch" management." Other things I read said it was based on the file size which we definitely aren't reaching with less than 100,000 records in total. I can't find any documentation regarding this change.  Does anyone know anything about it or have had the same things happen where your 2.0 query suddenly started batching where it didn't before with the same number of records?  This change is breaking integrations that work with our records because they aren't setup for receiving multiple files so any information you can give me regarding why/how this changed or how we can fix it would be appreciated. I tried asking support but thus far they have said that it isn't part of standard support for them to even tell me about a change to how Bulk 2.0 works and to just check the documentation which is the same as it was before.  I tried searching for how to change the 2.0 query to set a specific number of records or max # of records before the query was batched but all I was finding was for 1.0 not 2.0.  I can't find any documentation regarding how the "automatic batch management" actually decides to batch records.
What can we do to fix this?

We ran into the same problem on the same date, our previously un-batched query started batching.  To overcome this we added an ORDER BY statement to the query which results in PK Chunking being disabled for the query.  This is a hacky workaround, but solved for us.
Hope that helps.

Thanks!  We added the max records thing to the query and that made it so the results came all in one request instead of in their batches but I'm not sure how well that would work with larger queries.  We're trying to figure out future proofing our code to check for the locator in the header.
